# std::remove_if doesn't work correctly in c++

Tags: c++, std

I want to remove all element that are greater than 4 and this program prints : 4 3 1 8 1 and is not correct

```
std::vector<int> arr1 = { 4, 6, 3, 8, 1 };
std::remove_if(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), [](int i) {return i>4; });
    print(arr1);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`std::remove_if` doesn't actually erase any elements. It only moves the elements to be retained to the front of the `vector`, and returns an iterator to the first element to be removed. (This applies to any contiguous container, not just `vector`).

You need to then call `std::vector::erase` from that iterator to the `end` of the `vector` to actually erase the elements that have been removed from `arr1`:

```
auto last = std::remove_if(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), [](int i) {return i>4; });
arr.erase(last, arr.end());
```

Comment: It doesn’t move elements to the end of the vector. It leaves whatever is at the end alone, and returns an iterator that points at the end of the sequence that results from removing elements that pass the test. Algorithms don’t know about containers; they operate on sequences. Anything after the end of the output sequence `[arr.begin(), last)` is junk.